# Implementation of generic struct with header

Tags: c, pointers, generics, void-pointers

I'm a little confused about it.
The exercise is very long so I hope I wrote everything that's relevant for my question.
I have a given header file (part of it):

```
typedef void *(*copy_element)(const void *);
typedef void *(*free_element)(void **);

typedef struct group {
    size_t group_size;
    void **data;
    copy_element copy_element_func;
    free_element free_element_func;
} group;

group *group_alloc(copy_element copy_element_func, free_element free_element_func);
void group_free(group **p);
int add(group *group, const void *value);
```

I need to implement `group.c` as a generic struct.
My question is how can I implement add and alloc functions for `**data`?
With a known type I would use malloc and realloc with the size of the type, but here I'm not sure what to do.

```
group *group_alloc() {
    group *p = malloc(sizeof(group))
    if(p == NULL) {
        //
    }
    p->group_size = 0;

    void **ptr = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    p->data = ptr;
    return p;
}
```

In the exercise, Group should contain a dynamic array of values.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not certain you need double indirection there. Why `void**` instead of just `void*`?

Comment: The header file was given in the exercise Im working on.

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for a void pointer in group_alloc? Just make the data member a void* instead of void**, set it to NULL and later allocate memory. Or better yet, create a union with the datatypes that may be stored  in data and use that union type instead of void.

Comment: @user3265447 If it is an exercise, it might be worth posting the exercise aswell. Currently i don't see, why you'd need a void**

Comment: If that's an exercise given, it's hard to say what is expected of you. I would not bother allocating any memory for `data` in `group_alloc`, and just set `data` to nullptr. When you are ready to set the member, you'd allocate memory as required. But in academia world, anything is possible,

Comment: Same way as with non-void pointer. You allocate as much memory as needed with `malloc` and assign result to the `data`.

Comment: Ok so later when I want to allocate memory to data, with function `group add(group *g, const void *value)`.
When data is still NULL, how would I do so with the void pointer? I need to know the size of the type for malloc, but with void its unknown.
Sorry for the confustion, this generic functions topic is unclear to me.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something. void *has no size*.  data *is* a void*, a void *pointer*.  You do need to know how much memory you want to allocate. Then you store the pointer you get from malloc in data. Post the exercise already. It's hard to help you without knowing what you actually need/want to do.

Comment: It can be done like this. Whether it's a good idea depends on how it will be used later on. The benefit of the double pointer is that you can allocate `group` before you even know how much data you actually need. But again... how is this to be used?

Comment: Why do you need a double pointer for that?

Comment: @user3265447 I see the idea ... but please don't add explanations in comments. Instead edit the question and put the explanation there

Comment: @lulle In order to allocate a `group` without knowing the size of the real data

Comment: Maybe i am missing the obvious, but what prevents me from allocating memory to 'data' later, if it is a single pointer?

Comment: I think the idea is to avoid a situation where `data` is NULL. But then again... it's just a guess... we need to know how this will be used in order to see if it's a good idea

Comment: Well, then you have a pointer to a void pointer which is... NULL or uninitialized initially? I don't see how that is better. But i guess without seeing the exercise, this leads to nothing.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't write the whole exercise cause it's a lot, but I hope its enough for you to understand my question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "generic struct"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you should not care for the size nor the type of the elements, because the caller shall provide 2 functions that deal with copy and deallocation of those elements, so you can *at the `group` functions level* handle them as fully opaque pointers.

Here is a possible implementation. This code also contains a small demo showing how to handle null terminated strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef void *(*copy_element)(const void *);
typedef void *(*free_element)(void **);

typedef struct group {
    size_t group_size;
    void **data;
    copy_element copy_element_func;
    free_element free_element_func;
} group;

group *group_alloc(copy_element copy_element_func, free_element free_element_func);
void group_free(group **p);
int add(group *group, const void *value);

/***
Allocate a new group that will use the 2 provided functions.
The group will be initially empty
*/
group *group_alloc(copy_element copy_element_func, free_element free_element_func) {
    group * g = malloc(sizeof(*g));
    g->group_size = 0;
    g->data = NULL;
    g->copy_element_func = copy_element_func;
    g->free_element_func = free_element_func;
    return g;
}

/*********
* Add a new element to a group.
* Will use the copy_element_func member to build a copy of the element
* This implementation returns the number of elements in the group
*/
int add(group *group, const void *value) {
    size_t sz = group->group_size + 1;  // do not change anything on alloc error
    void **data = realloc(group->data, sz * sizeof(void *));
    if (data == NULL) {  // allocation error
        return 0;
    }
    // use copy_element_func to build a copy of the element
    data[sz - 1] = group->copy_element_func(value);
    group->group_size = sz;
    group->data = data;
    return (int) sz;
}

/******************
* Free a group.
* First free all elements of the group (using the free_element_func member)
* and then the group itself
*/
void group_free(group **p) {
    group *g = *p;
    if (g != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < g->group_size; i++) {
            // again use free_element_func that should be able to free an element
            g->free_element_func(g->data + i);
        }
        free(g);
    }
    *p = NULL;
}

// Example functions for null terminated strings
void * copy_string(const void *input) {
    return strdup(input);
}

void * free_string(void **str) {
    free(*str);
    *str = NULL;
    return *str;
}

// demo code
int main() {
    group *g = group_alloc(&copy_string, &free_string);
    int i = add(g, "foo");
    printf("%d\n", i);   // should display 1
    i = add(g, "bar");
    printf("%d\n", i);   // should display 2
    for (i = 0; i < g->group_size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ((char **)g->data)[i]);  // should display foo then bar
    }
    group_free(&g);
    printf("%p\n", g);   // should display a NULL pointer
    return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: this code blindly assumes the availability of the `strdup` function, while it is optional and does not test for allocation errors...

Comment: Thanks it really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, i think you are supposed to do the following:

`group_size` member holds the number of data entries in the group.

`data` member is an array of pointers that point to the objects that were added to the group.

With this combination of struct and function definitions, you can't do much other than adding pointers to objects to the `data` array in the group.

In the `group_alloc` function, you just allocate memory for the `group` object itself and initialize its members:

```
group *group_alloc(copy_element copy_element_func, free_element free_element_func){
    group *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
    if(ret == NULL){
        return(NULL);
    }
    ret->group_size = 0; //initially the group holds no pointers to objects
    ret->data = NULL;
    ret->free_element_func = free_element_func;
    ret->copy_element_func = copy_element_func;
    return(ret);
}
```

When an object is to be added, the add function is called.
The caller passes the `group` in which the object should be stored and a pointer to the object. You have to make space for another pointer in your `data` array:

```
int add(group *group, const void *value){
    void **newData = realloc(group->data, (group->data_size + 1) * sizeof(*group->data)); //Grow the data array by one to store an additional pointer. 
    //realloc may return NULL, in that case an error occured, but you don't want to overwrite your existing data pointer
    if(newData == NULL){
        return(-1); //return -1 to indicate an error occured
    }
    group->data = newData;
    group->data[group->data_size] = value; //store the pointer to the object in the last array field
    group->data_size++; //increment data_size
    return(0); //return 0 to indicate success
}
```

I am kind of questioning the usefulness of this construct since you can add pointers to arbitrary data to the group, zero information about what kind of data and wether or not it has to be free'd later is stored. You could add a bunch of pointers to static objects and a bunch of pointers to dynamically allocated objects and you would have no idea which of the objects have to be freed.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now